# Use features from npm package rxjs without using npm install in Angular app

Tags: angular, npm, rxjs

I have an existing Angular 4 application, which uses rxjs 5.4.1. For one of the new feature that we need to develop, we need to update rxjs to 6.3+. However, there are lots of changes with rxjs, hence it is breaking lot of my existing code.

I have some new features in updated rxjs package - ***tap, reduce, scan, pluck***. So want to see if there is any good way to take those features from node modules and run them from my code itself, by placing them inside my app folder.

Can someone guide me on how to implement this? appreciate any pointers. I tried to google, but could not find any good solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

RxJs 5 and 6 are not compatible but there is a compatibility package, you can experiment if Angular will work with the compat package but I would suggest that upgrading your Angular project to 6+ would be the wisest move if you want RxJs 6.3+.

The upgrade from Angular 4 to 6 is not that painful.

Comment: Could you pls let me know the compat package details? is it https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat?  Also, is there anyway I can work with Angular4 itself, if I use compat package? I need to use these features from rxjs 6.3+ - tap, reduce, scan, pluck